# Count double in object and total for each JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I need a bit help to get the double count and total price for each person. My object

```
const obj = [
  {'name':'sven','price':'10'},
  {'name':'jan','price':'12'},
  {'name':'john','price':'5'},
  {'name':'nick','price':'13'},
  {'name':'sven','price':'11'},
  {'name':'jan','price':'7'},
  {'name':'nick','price':'9'},
];
```

From this object I am counting double from key 'name'. e.g. sven 2, jan 1, john 1, nick 2.
I use this code for that

```
const counts = [];
obj.map((x)=>{ 
  counts[x[0]] = (counts[x[0]] || 0) + 1;
});
```

Now I need also the total count of key 'price' saves together with each person and I can't seem to find a way to do so.

result should be an array of object e.g.

```
counts = [
  {'person':'sven','count':'2','totalPrice':'21'},
  {'person':'jan','count':'2','totalPrice':'19'}
]
```

I know how to get double and I know how to count total, but not in the same loop and save as 1 object.
If someone could help me a bit pointing the right direction please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) solution which checks whether the array contains an item with the same `name` property, and if so, increments its `totalPrice` property by the item's `price` property and its `count` property by 1.

```js
const arr = [
  {'name':'sven','price':'10'},
  {'name':'jan','price':'12'},
  {'name':'john','price':'5'},
  {'name':'nick','price':'13'},
  {'name':'sven','price':'11'},
  {'name':'jan','price':'7'},
  {'name':'nick','price':'9'},
];

const result = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  const found = a.find(e => e.name == b.name);
  if(found){
    found.totalPrice += +b.price;
    found.count++;
  }else{
    a.push({name:b.name, totalPrice: +b.price, count: 1})
  }
  return a
}, [])

console.log(result)
```